# TabItem switching not working properly in iOS13 devices

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview, swiftui-tabview

I have created demo of Tab bar with two tabItems. Each tab-item have view controller in it.

On switching tabs, it is **not** showing its respective UI.

This is happening on **iOS 13** only.

**Code:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private enum Tab: Hashable {
           case one
           case two
    }
    @State private var selectedIndex = Tab.one
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
            DetestVXViewController(bgColor: .red).tabItem {
                Text("123")
            }.tag(Tab.one)
            DetestVXViewController(bgColor: .green).tabItem {
                Text("321")
            }.tag(Tab.two)
        }
       
    }
}
```

**====**

Attaching images of iOS 13 and 15 both.

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us the `DetestVXViewController` code, in particular how you use the `bgColor`.

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = bgColor is the only code in viewDidLoad. Its working in iOS14.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tag` seems overkill unless you need to keep track of said tab for quick actions or another purpose. You can still use tag in this though if needed. You can use `@State` property for the selection also if needed. You can easily switch tabs with the following example.

[image]
[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(1..<3) { index in
                SomeView(title: "\(index)")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "\(index).circle.fill")
                        Text("\(index)")3
                    }
                //.tag(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No @Cole. It won't work too when you will use some uiviewrepresentable View in tab. This is clearly a issue in ios13.